# Python 3.4 is missing _ssl.pyd

Tags: python, ssl, python-3.4, ubuntu-10.04, tls1.2

Environment: 
Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS
Python 3.4.3

I have a working python 3.4 Flask HTTPS server running perfectly on Windows. I need to transfer this over to an existing Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS server. I have built python 3.4 on there with no problems but when I run my web server it fails with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./server.py", line 3, in <module>
    from app import create_app
  File "/opt/license-server/app/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from config import config
  File "/opt/license-server/config.py", line 9, in <module>
    class Config:
  File "/opt/license-server/config.py", line 25, in Config
    LDAP_TLS_VERSION = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2'
```

I did some digging around on Windows using pyCharm to find out what is going on and it seems that PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2 is defined in _ssl.py which I believe comes from _ssl.pyd. Neither _ssl.py or _ssl.pyd exists on the Ubuntu python install which leads me to believe that I'm missing some option or something when compiling but I cannot find any reference to this on the python web site on what is missing or how to get the TLS-1.2 stuff.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

When you build your Python 3.4 from sources, at the end of the build you get a report saying which modules were not built. My bet is that the ssl module was not build, because your Ubuntu installation doesn't have SSL packages installed. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
```

then try to **rebuild your Python 3.4** and see if the SSL module is built.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. libssl-dev and openssl were already installed and up to date. Just to be sure deleted the build folder, ran ./configure and then a make to force rebuild of the targets and I got the following output:Python build finished successfully!
The necessary bits to build these optional modules were not found:
_lzma
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name. Which mentions nothing about OpenSSL and sadly it still does not work I get the same error when running the server.

Comment: Looks like _ssl.cpython-34m.so which could be similar to the windows pyd is being built according to the build logs but it doesn't seem to contain what I need. Looking like I should just move to a windows server and be done with it.